# Creating a sith lightning effect

Tags: effects, final-cut-express, special-effects

How do you create a sith lightning effect? I am getting into special effects, and was wondering how you do this. I have FCE 4 & 3.5. I'd rather not have to use a different program, but...

Comment: Is that "sith" as in Star Wars?

Comment: Yeah, I am starting to get into SPFX. I am getting familiar with how to create SPFX and was curious about sith lightning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With FCE I think your best option would be a plugin or something. I know you can make them with Apple Motion and After Effects though, or a really simple one with good ol' iMovie HD.

Good luck in your search for the force.

Comment: How can you make them with Motion and After Effects? Could you elaborate a bit?

Comment: After Effects has built in lightning effects. Tutorials are all over the place... for example http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=puN_qxndOoI. As for Motion, I don't think it has a built in plugin, but according to this post you should be able to find loops you might then edit. http://forums.creativecow.net/thread/170/862970

Comment: No problem :) I'm glad it did!